Has there ever been a proposal to have judges who are also doctors to deal with legal cases that are also medicine?
There are occasions where the justice system makes decisions that can be described as being also medical decisions.  These range from the high level, such as the general availability of a drug to the individual, such as whether to incarcerate an individual who is at risk of suicide.
From my more biomedical than legal point of view these decisions hinge more on knowledge of medical decision making and scientific evidence than legal decision making and the details of the law.  One could imagine one solution to this would be to have some small percentage of the judiciary drawn from doctors who have an interest in law.  These could then handle the relatively small number of cases that revolve around decisions that are closer to medical than criminal justice.
Has there ever been such a proposal?

It should be pointed out that the job of the Supreme Court is not to decide about whether or not a drug should be available on medical grounds, but rather to decide on the procedural question if the FDA is allowed to decide on the matter or not. The Supreme Court doesn't decide if a political decision is good or bad, they decide whether it was constitutional or not constitutional.

@Philipp I read the Texas ruling and it seemed to me to pretty fundamentally misunderstand medical decision making.  It is that that really prompted the question.

You should state which jurisdiction you are considering. In the UK, we have specialised courts called 'Tribunals' to decide some issues including the detention of mental patients, payment of disability benefits, provision of special educational services, etc. The tribunal judiciary includes medical practitioners, Chartered Surveyors, people who are experienced in dealing with the physical and mental needs of disabled people, and people who have served in the armed forces to name a few.

@MichaelHarvey I am interested in any jurisdiction.  That sounds like most of an answer.

Where would you even find judges who were also doctors? Who has 10+ years to kill in back-to-back postgraduate work?

@Cadence I do not know.  It just seems easier to me to train a doctor in the law required to answer these questions than to train a judge in the medicine.

Note that the general idea is that judges don't need have any particular special domain knowledge relevant to a case they get but rather are educated enough to realize their lack of knowledge and then ask a suitable domain expert.

@quarague In the second example the judge is being asked to choose between incarceration and freedom for a suicidal person.  From my point of view that is a clinical decision about the most appropriate treatment for an medical condition.

True. And in that case the idea is that the judge asks some suitably qualified doctor what they recommend and why and then follows the opinion of the domain expert.

Judges typically aren't experts in another field like medicine or engineering or psychology or... . They can get expert opinions though. And they need to be able to understand them and make them consistent with the law.

Very few people trained in the law (i.e. lawyers) actually become judges (because there are a lot of Lawyers and few positions for judges) so I don't think it's easier to "train a doctor in the law" and have this doctor turned lawyer become a judge than to have a person how who is already a judge attend a 4 years of medical school. The length of education for lawyers (typically 3 years) is comparable to doctor (4 years) is comparable so I'm not sure how you would even arrive at that conclusion.

@quarague I do not know, but I suspect a doctor would understand that having control over the process could be inherently therapeutic and so would priorities the patient having input into the decision.

Usually the need of domain knowledge is fulfilled by asking an expert witness for opinion

The expectation is that the lawmakers will get advice from the domain experts when they draft the relevant laws. Then the judges just have to decide how the law applies to a specific case. So the laws on whether a drug should be legal will be based on that expertise, and judges don't have to make their own decisions.

"Being a doctor" isn't a binary state; medicine is huge. A neurologist probably knows more about kidney function than someone with no medical expertise, true, but when you want expert decisions on a matter to do with kidneys you get a nephrologist, not any random doctor. So your proposal would need medical judges from loads of different specialities, not just "a small percentage who are doctors", and enough of them to run independent appeals courts, etc. It just works better to have the legal experts find the experts they need for each case than to try to staff courts with dual-experts.

@Ben My issue is with the decision making process.  It does not take a specialist to understand the harm caused by incarceration.

I am not aware of such a proposal, although England has a Mental Health Tribunal that deals with issues involve medical decisions made by a panel of judges including at least one legally trained judge and at least one judge with social work or clinical psychology or psychiatry experience.
In U.S. practice, the norm is to have these decisions made primarily by judges and juries who are informed by expert witness testimony offered by the parties (which is usually mandatory except in the clearest and most obvious of cases).
One exception to this rule is U.S. practice is that 72 hour hold orders that involuntarily commit someone to inpatient mental health care when that person is a threat to themselves or others can often be made by a suitably qualified medical professional (or by law enforcement) without obtaining a court order.
The basic problem with the proposal is that professionals with dual legal and medical training are vanishingly rare. I've never encountered a judge with that kind of qualification and I am aware of only a couple of privately practicing lawyers with those qualifications, anywhere in the U.S. over multiple decades. Dr. Joseph Ramos, for example, is a rare exception who proves the rule. And, any judge needs legal as well as medical knowledge.
Lots of legal cases involving mental and physical health (e.g. medical malpractice, termination of life support, mental health evaluations, guardianships, etc.), come up on a regular basis. See, e.g. the 2022 Annual Report from Colorado's state courts (breaking out annual case loads by case type). For example, Colorado has 1791 cases a year adjudicating incapacity for an adult in a civil case, alone, without considering insanity defense and competency issues in criminal cases, or medical malpractice cases, or involuntary commitment cases.
Certainly, there are far more such cases than all of the jointly trained medical and legal professionals available could handle managing even if everyone with these qualifications was employed full-time as as a judge doing so.
